# MFP 8.0 - Intermittent invalid_scope error after login

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli, mfp

We have configured MFP OAuth Authentication and enabled single user session on server. Currently we are getting intermittent **invalid_scope** error on next adapter request after successful login.

MFP Server version - **8.0.0.00-20181004-0631**

MFP Cli version - **8.0.0-2017102406**

Plugin installed version -

cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2018112111
cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore 8.0.2018112111

Below error we are getting at client side while invoking procedure.

```
{
   errorCode: "222"
   errorMsg: "wl-oauth-prevent-redirect"
   responseHeaders:{
       alt-svc: "clear"
       content-language: "en-US"
       content-length: "0"
       date: "Sat, 16 Nov 2019 03:19:38 GMT"
       location: "https://mfpredirecturi?error=invalid_scope"
       server: "rhino-core-shield"
       via: "1.1 google"
       x-powered-by: "Servlet/3.0"
   }
   _proto_: Object
   responseText: ""
   status: 222
   statusText: "wl-oauth-prevent-redirect"
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the adapter? Are you passing scope explicitly in the Wlresourcerequest API?

Comment: Yes @VivinK for all secure adapter calls we are passing scope explicitly as below. 

resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, method, { 'scope': 'UserLogin' });

This invalid_scope is happening intermittently. Even we tried by removing scope from WLResourceRequest API to see mfp will take scope by default but still same issue.

Comment: The first thing to check is , if "UserLogin" is indeed your scope. Scope is what protects your resource. If UserLogin is your security check, then you are doing it wrong.